# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: Unable to send node information

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, terraform

I am trying to use terraform to create a Service Fabric Cluster via combination of VMSS, VNETs, NSGs, etc. Unfortunately there isn't an official terraform provider for service fabric, so I am using an ARM template via `azurerm_template_deployment`.

All resources get created successfully via `terraform apply` and I am able to RDP into one of the VMs in the scale set. Unfortunately, even after 30-60 minutes, the Azure Portal for Service Fabric resource Status reads `Waiting for nodes` with no nodes showing up in the table.

When I RDP into the VM, I see several warning/error events in Event Viewer. All events come from `ServiceFabricNodeBootstrapAgent`:

### 1.

```
Info: Bootstrapping local node
```

### 2.

```
Info: PUT https://westus.servicefabric.azure.com/runtime/clusters/GUID_redacted/nodes/node_name_redacted
{"nodeTypeRef":"fronend","ipAddress":"192.168.0.8","faultDomain":"fd:/4","upgradeDomain":"4"}
```

### 3. Info

```
     Using client certificate: [Version]
       V3

     [Subject]
       CN=AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient
       Simple Name: AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient
       DNS Name: AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient

     [Issuer]
       CN=AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient
       Simple Name: AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient
       DNS Name: AzureServiceFabric-AnonymousClient

     ... etc ...
```

### 4.

```
ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
```

### 5.

```
System.Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)

   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.WrpTopologyService.UpdateNodeInfo(String machineName, NodeDescription nodeDescription)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

### 6.

```
ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: Unable to send node information
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.<RunOnce>d__11.MoveNext()
```

It seems that `ServiceFabricNodeBootstrapAgent`, a Windows service gets installed, but that's it. None of the service fabric runtime services ever get installed and I am not sure even why that API is used, or why it is returning 401. Anyone out there seen this problem?

Creating a cluster from the marketplace as well as via exported ARM template with powershell works just fine.

Comment: Does each VM have correct ACL for certificates used in SF?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, even creating unsecured cluster fails in the same way.

Comment: Did you ever determine the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and due to timing constraints of the project, ended up creating the clusters manually via the Azure Portal (sigh)